# verifying state and input react issue

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a verification method in an React class Component below and seems like it won't verify the "Username" field correctly even though it is similarly written as the First Name and Last Name fields.

For inputs that are less than 2 characters or over 15 characters it'll give an error. However, for the Username field, it only verifies when the length of "userName" is less than 2 characters and stays that way forever, unlike the other 2 text fields where it gives me the other error message when the length is over 15.. I basically just updated the id, value, htmlFor, invalid, onChange, and onBlur for the Username field..

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Just wondering what other experienced JS devs see that I might doing incorrectly.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, Col, FormFeedback } from 'reactstrap';

class RegistrationForm extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        //1
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            userName: '',
            phoneNum: '',
            testField: '',
            email: '',
            agree: false,
            touched: {
                firstName: false,
                lastName: false,
                userName: false,
                phoneNum: false,
                email: false,
                testField: false
            }
        }

        //3
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    // 2
    handleInputChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const name = target.name;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;

        this.setState({[name]: value}) //bracket notation to use the "name" to find the matching state property
    }

    //4
    handleSubmit(event){
        console.log("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));
        alert("Current state is: " + JSON.stringify(this.state));

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    handleBlur = (property) => () => {
        this.setState({
            touched: {...this.state.touched, [property]:true}
        })
    }

    //Check parameters of inputs
    check(firstName, lastName, userName, phoneNum, email, testField){
        const errors = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            phoneNum: '',
            userName: '',
            email:'',
            testField:''
        }

        if(this.state.touched.firstName){
            if(firstName.length < 2){
                errors.firstName = 'First name must be at least 2 characters';
            } else if (firstName.length > 15){
                errors.firstName = 'First name must be equal to or less than 15 characters';
            }
        }

        if(this.state.touched.lastName){
            if(lastName.length < 2){
                errors.lastName = 'Last name must be at least 2 characters';
            } else if (lastName.length > 15){
                errors.lastName = 'Last name must be equal to or less than 15 characters';
            }
        }

        if(this.state.touched.userName){
            if(userName.length < 2){
                errors.userName = 'Username must be at least 2 characters';
            } else if (userName.length > 15){
                errors.userName = 'Username must be equal to or less than 15 characters';
            }
        }

        if(this.state.touched.testField){
            if(testField.length < 2){
                errors.testField = 'Username must be at least 2 characters';
            } else if (testField.length > 15){
                errors.testField = 'Username must be equal to or less than 15 characters';
            }
        }

        if(this.state.touched.email && !email.includes('@')){
            errors.email = 'Your email must include an "@".'
        }

        const reg = /^\d+$/;
        if (this.state.touched.phoneNum && !reg.test(phoneNum)) {
            errors.phoneNum = 'The phone number should contain only numbers.';
        }

        return errors
    }

    render(){

        //Display "state" from "check" method
        const errors = this.check(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.phoneNum, this.state.userName, this.state.email, this.state.testField);

        return(
            <div className="row row-content">
                <div className="col-12 mt-3">
                    <h2>Register for an Account & Stay Updated!</h2>
                    <hr />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-10">

                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="firstName" md={2}>First Name</Label>
                            <Col md={6}>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="firstName"
                                    placeholder='First Name'
                                    name="firstName"
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                    onBlur={this.handleBlur("firstName")}
                                    invalid={errors.firstName}
                                    value={this.state.firstName}                                    
                                />
                                <FormFeedback>{errors.firstName}</FormFeedback>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="testField" md={2}>Test Field</Label>
                            <Col md={6}>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="testField"
                                    placeholder='Test Field'
                                    name="testField"
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                    onBlur={this.handleBlur("testField")}
                                    invalid={errors.testField}
                                    value={this.state.testField}                                    
                                />
                                <FormFeedback>{errors.testField}</FormFeedback>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
        
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="lastName" md={2}>Last Name</Label>
                            <Col md={6}>
                                <Input 
                                    type="text"
                                    id="lastName"
                                    placeholder='Last Name'
                                    name="lastName"
                                    value={this.state.lastName}
                                    invalid={errors.lastName}
                                    onBlur={this.handleBlur("lastName")}
                                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
                                />
                                <FormFeedback>{errors.lastName}</FormFeedback>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
    
                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Label htmlFor="userName" md={2}>Username</Label>
                            <Col md={6}>
                                <Input
                                     type="text"
                                     id="userName"
                                     placeholder='Username'
                                     name="userName"
                                     value={this.state.userName}
                                     invalid={errors.userName}
                                     onBlur={this.handleBlur("userName")}
                                     onChange={this.handleInputChange}                                
                                />
                                <FormFeedback>{errors.userName}</FormFeedback>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="phoneNum">Phone Number</Label>
                            <Input 
                                type="tel"
                                id="phoneNum"
                                placeholder="Phone Number"
                                name="phoneNum"
                                value={this.state.phoneNum}
                                invalid={errors.phoneNum}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                onBlur={this.handleBlur('phoneNum')}

                            />
                            <FormFeedback>{errors.phoneNum}</FormFeedback>
                        </FormGroup>
               
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="email">Email</Label>
                            <Input
                                type="email"
                                id="email"
                                placeholder="Email"
                                name="email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                invalid={errors.email}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                onBlur={this.handleBlur('email')}
                            />
                            <FormFeedback>{errors.email}</FormFeedback>
                        </FormGroup>

                        <FormGroup row>
                            <Col md={6}>
                                <FormGroup check>
                                    <Label check>
                                        <Input 
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            name="agree"
                                            checked={this.state.agree}
                                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                        />{' '}
                                        <strong>May we contact you?</strong>
                                    </Label>

                                </FormGroup>
                            </Col>
                            
                            <Col md={4}>
                                <Input type="select" name="contactType">
                                    <option>By Phone</option>
                                    <option>By Email</option>
                                </Input>
                            </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                        
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Button type="submit" value="submit" color="primary">Submit</Button>
                        </FormGroup>
                        
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
}


class Register extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <RegistrationForm />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pass arguments to the `check` function in the wrong order.

```
check(firstName, lastName, userName, phoneNum, email, testField) {...}
```

But in your render function you invoke `check` as such:

```
const errors = this.check(
  this.state.firstName,
  this.state.lastName,
  this.state.phoneNum, // <-- userName parameter
  this.state.userName, // <-- phoneNum parameter
  this.state.email,
  this.state.testField
);
```

The order should be `firstName`, `lastName`, **`userName`**, then `phoneNum`, `email`, and `testField`.

```
const errors = this.check(
  this.state.firstName,
  this.state.lastName,
  this.state.userName,
  this.state.phoneNum,
  this.state.email,
  this.state.testField
);
```

I suggest to avoid argument ordering issues in the future you should pass a single object argument so order is irrelevant.

```
check({ firstName, lastName, userName, phoneNum, email, testField }) {...}
```

And pass `this.state` directly to `check` and let it destructure the field values.

```
const errors = this.check(this.state);
```

[image: Edit verifying-state-and-input-react-issue]

Comment: Drew.. you are absolutely amazing. Thank you for saving me again! Two times in a row... honestly I did not realize they had to be in order BUT that makes sense because "check" is a method, which is a function, that takes parameters in the order I initiated them as. That makes perfect sense.